# Add wmts layer from Geoserver to ArcGIS viewer for Flex

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-flex-viewer, wmts

Is there anyone out there who has set wmts layer from Geoserver to ArcGIS viewer for flex?

I am trying to do that but without any luck.

```
<layer label="Sample WMTS layer" type="wmts" visible="true" useproxy="false" imageformat="gif" url="http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts" style="_null" servicemode="KVP" layerid="world" tilematrixsetid="EPSG:4326"/>
```

If I change the type to "wms" it works like a charm.

Anyone?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?
I am trying to figure this out my self, this is the link which I use to try to solve it https://geonet.esri.com/thread/49272 .
I will keep you posted if will figure this out.

Comment: No we did not. So we just used WMS instead of WMTS. But we are still looking for answers.
If we find the answer we will let you know. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my project I had to use proxy with WMTS layers, otherwise they would not work.

**edit**

As noted in the thread in the comment by @user28386:

> The issue is likely that the server does have a crossdomain.xml but it
>   only has "allow-http-request-headers-from" and does not have an entry
>   for "allow-access-from".

and

> Unlike  the WMS type, there is no skipgetcababilities attribute. Since
>   this is  the case, if the WMTS service does not have a crosdomain file
>   associated  with it, you will need to provide a proxy page URL.